# CSS - Apply css rule if two css classes are present with other css classes

Tags: css, angularjs

I have form with input fields. The classes which are applied to input field are changed on click of submit button. I want to apply css rule if two css classes are applied with other css classes

Ex.

```
<input ng-model="formField.val" type="text" name="103" 
       class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
       ng-disabled="readOnlyFlag" required="">
```

on click of submit button, the new css classes ng-invalid & ng-touched  are applied with other css classes. I want apply css rule if ng-invalid  & ng-touched are applied with other css classes.

```
 <input ng-model="formField.val" type="text" name="103" 
       class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" 
       ng-disabled="readOnlyFlag" required="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add styling for input when it has two classes:

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
  background:red;
  color:red;
}
```

Or if you want to use code use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) :

```
angular.element(myElement).hasClass('my-class');
angular.element(myElement).addClass('new-class');
angular.element(myElement).removeClass('old-class');
```

Code is copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192705/how-to-check-if-element-has-class-with-angularjs) question.